# Pass $_GET variable through ajax call's php file

Tags: ajax

I have an jQuery AJAX call that lists records from database based on $_GET variable called "website_identificator". Imagine the main file is called "index.php" (where the AJAX call is presented) and the PHP script file that is called by the AJAX is called "phpscript.php". Now also imagine that I'm using the $_GET "website_identificator" to decide what to show on this page, but this $_GET "website_identificator" is beneficial for the PHP script file so it can filter the records and show the right ones. How to I use this $_GET variable in "phpscript.php", because when I try to use it like this:

```
<?php $getVar = $_GET['website_identificator']; ?>
```

PHP understands it like "phpscript.php?website_identificator=STRING" but not "index.php?website_identificator=STRING" despite the fact that I called the file through AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you call `index.php` with the query parameter `website_identificator`? You have to include that value in the AJAX request and pass it on to `phpscript.php`. There is no magical way to retrieve the query parameters from another script, both are standalone.